# Having trouble writing numbers from C# to SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to write some numbers to a table in `SQL` using `C#` in `Visual Studio`. When I run this code, I have a catch statement that prints:

> Connection property has not been initialized.

I'm thinking there might be something wrong with my 5th line of code? I'm very new to `C#` and `SQL`, and there was an error recognizing the connection object, but I was able to click on a little drop down and assign it something to get rid of the error.

```
sSql = "INSERT INTO FAI.emc_dept (DepartmentID, Department) " +
"VALUES (" +
"@DepartmentID," +
"@Department";
SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(sSql, FAIDataSet.Connection);
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", "abc");
ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", "def")
ins.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Have you opened the connection?

Comment: Your title points to problem in `ins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DepartmentID", "abc");` where an int value is expected an you are passing `abc`, but your description says something about connection....

Comment: Also your sql statement is missing the closing `)` at the end.

Comment: I initialized a connection earlier in the code with

cnSqlSvr = new SqlConnection(sSql);
cnSqlSvr.Open();

and tested the connection - it does work

Comment: @alex_stock But you're passing in `FAIDataSet.Connection` to the `SqlCommand` instead of `snSqlSvr`.

Comment: @habib no it's a string because the IDs have numbers and letters

Comment: @juharr good point although the problem still persists

Comment: What is 'FAIDataSet.Connection'? Is it a SqlConnection instance? The error message indicates that the Connection property of your command object is null. You need to set it to a SqlConnection instance.

Comment: @juharr so what should I have instead of ??? in 

SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(sSql, ???)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based on comments:

> cnSqlSvr = new SqlConnection(sSql);

But `sSql` is not the connection string. Replace this with:

```
cnSqlSvr = new SqlConnection("your connection string");
```

And this:

```
SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(sSql, FAIDataSet.Connection);
```

with:

```
SqlCommand ins = new SqlCommand(sSql, cnSqlSvr);
```